# Change JSON_Encode output format (Brackets and Commas)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array that is created in PHP, and then encoded into my javascript via JSON.

The Array is defined here:

```
$stmt -> bind_result($match_id, $hero, $mmr);
while($stmt -> fetch()){
    $grapharray[] = array($hero => $mmr);
}
```

and JSON encoded here:

```
$grapharray_labelled = array(
    "label" => "MMR Over time",
    "data" => $grapharray          
);
```

and here:

`var graphdata = <?php echo JSON_encode($grapharray_labelled); ?>;`

### The output when I run my webpage is that `graphdata` =:

```
{
"label":"MMR Over time",
"data":[
        {"Rubick":6524},
        {"Lion":6550},
        {"Magnus":6565},
        {"Keeper of the Light":6566}
        ]
}
```

### **However** I would like it to be like this:

```
{
"label":"MMR Over time",
"data":[
        ["Rubick", 6524],
        ["Lion", 6550],
        ["Magnus", 6565],
        ["Keeper of the Light", 6566]
        ]
}
```

Reason: 
I would like to change the format because I am trying to get flot to work, and flot accepts an array of arrays as the datatype.

Otherwise: Is there a better way to transfer an array from PHP to JavaScript with my desired format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$grapharray[] = array($hero => $mmr);
```

TO:

```
$grapharray[] = array($hero, $mmr);
```

Comment: I'm incredibly angry. Both at you for revealing my stupidity to me, and at myself for being so stupid. Would you believe that this stumped me for hours?

Comment: But in all seriousness. THANK YOU.

Comment: @k4kuz0 Don't worry it happens with everyone sometimes. It proves you're a struggles. Good Luck